# Codeigniter pagination id at the last segment of url

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

Hi I have working pagination function in other sites but here

```
public function category($id=null)
{
    $config = array();
    $config["base_url"] = base_url() . "view/category/".$id;
    $config["total_rows"] = $this->viewmodel->record_count_category_post($data['category']);
    $config["per_page"] = 6;
    $config['num_links'] = 10;
    $this->pagination->initialize($config);  
    $page = ($this->uri->segment(4)) ? $this->uri->segment(4) : 0;
    $config['display_pages'] = FALSE;
    $data["links"] = $this->pagination->create_links();

}
```

I could not figure why pagination not working. How could I make pagination working if the URL contains number (id) at the last segment ?

Comment: Did you create route for it? http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html

Comment: @wolfgang1983 I haven't created any route there

Comment: This is your full code?

Comment: Where is your query with limit to get data?

Answer (score 0):

Change your `$page = ($this->uri->segment(4)) ? $this->uri->segment(4) : 0;` to:

```
if($this->uri->segment(4))
            {
                $config["per_page"] = (($this->uri->segment(4)) * 6) - 6;
            }
            else
            {
                $config["per_page"] = 0;
            }
```

Like this Sample Below:

```
public function category($id=null)
            {
            $config = array();
            $config["base_url"] = base_url() . "view/category/".$id;
            $config["total_rows"] = $this->viewmodel->record_count_category_post($data['category']);
            $config["per_page"] = 6;
            $config['num_links'] = 10;
            $this->pagination->initialize($config);  
        if($this->uri->segment(4))
                {
                    $config["per_page"] = (($this->uri->segment(4)) * 6) - 6;
                }
                else
                {
                    $config["per_page"] = 0;
                }
        $config['display_pages'] = FALSE;
         $data["links"] = $this->pagination->create_links();

         }
```

Answer (score 0):

change 
`public function category($id=null)`
to

`public function category($id=0)`

Because `NULL` will not return any segment...